# How to prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-i\overset{\to}{q}\cdot \overset{\to}{r}}d^3 r=\frac{4\pi}{m^2+q^2}?$

Tags: calculus

I would really appreciate if someone could help me about the  following: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-i\overset{\to}{q}\cdot \overset{\to}{r}}d^3 r=\frac{4\pi}{m^2+q^2}?$$
where $r=|\overset{\to}{r}|$, $q=|\overset{\to}{q}|$, $\overset{\to}{q}$ and $\overset{\to}{r}$ are three dimensional vectors, and $m$ is an scalar.

Thanks in advance.

What I've tried: using spherical coordinates, we have $d^3 r=dxdydz=r^2dr\sin \theta d\theta d\phi$, where $0\leq r<\infty$, $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, and $0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$. Then $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-i\overset{\to}{q}\cdot \overset{\to}{r}}d^3 r=\iiint \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-irq\cos\theta}r^2dr\sin \theta d\theta d\phi$$ $$=2\pi \iint \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-irq\cos\theta}r^2dr\sin \theta d\theta,$$ $$=2\pi \iint e^{-mr}e^{-irq\cos\theta}rdr\sin \theta d\theta,$$ where $r=|\overset{\to}{r}|$ and $q=|\overset{\to}{q}|$. Now how can I compute the last integral?

Comment: What is $d^{3}r$?

Comment: What is division by a vector $r$? Are you writing $\int_0^{\infty}$ for a triple integral? Please try to use standard notations from Calculus.

Comment: @geetha290krm you are right. sorry. I've just edied my question.

Comment: I suppose that the same symbol $r$ is here used for both the position vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ (or $(x,y,z)$ if you prefer) and for the length of it (i.e. the distance from origin). In $e^{-imr}/r$ it is a scalar, while in $e^{-iq\cdot r}$ it is a vector (and so is $q$).

Comment: @md2perpe This question comes from the form factor in particle physics. This is an exercise that I couldn't understand. I think you are right.

Comment: If $m$ and $q$ are both scalars, then we have $e^{-imr} e^{-iqr} = e^{-i(m+q)r}$ so the result should contain $m+q,$ not $m^2+q^2.$ Likewise, if $m$ and $q$ are both vectors, we would have $|m+q|$ in the result.

Comment: Also, I think that the integral should be over 3 dimensions (and all of space). Otherwise, when we have made one $r$ into the position vector, we don't know which position vector we should take for each radius $r$.

Comment: Hint: write the integrand as $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0 } \frac{e^{-i (m+q) r}}{r+a}$

Comment: @md2perpe By your good comments, I've just edited my question. Thank you four comments.

Comment: @geetha290krm I've used standard notations from Calculus. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I don't think there should be an imaginary unit in $e^{-imr}$ but just be $e^{-mr}.$ With the latter I get the expected result.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, $e^{-mr}$ is right.  Could you please wirte me your answer? I couldn't finish it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You will see it in a while.

Comment: @md2perpe Appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: let $u=\cos\theta$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to evaluate the following integral:
$$
I := \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \, \mathrm{d}^3 r,
$$
where $m$ is a constant scalar, $\mathbf{q}$ is a constant vector, $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector $(x,y,z)$ and $r=|\mathbf{r}|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is the distance from origin to the position.

Because of symmetry we can assume that $\mathbf{q} = q\hat{z},$ where $q$ is a scalar and $\hat{z}$ is the unit vector in the $z$ direction. We then have
$$
I 
= \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-q\hat{z}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \, \mathrm{d}^3 r
= \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}e^{-iqz} \, \mathrm{d}^3 r
.
$$

Introducing spherical (polar) coordinates,
$$
\mathbf{r} = (x,y,z) = (r\sin\theta\cos\phi, r\sin\theta\sin\phi, r\cos\theta),
$$
we get
$$
I = \int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^\pi \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} 
\frac{e^{-mr}}{r} e^{-iqr\cos\theta}  \, r^2 \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}r
\\
= 2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^\pi r e^{-mr} e^{-iqr\cos\theta} \, \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}r
\\
= 2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty r e^{-mr} \left[ \frac{1}{-iqr} e^{-iqr\cos\theta} \right]_{\theta=0}^\pi \mathrm{d}r
\\
= 2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty r e^{-mr} \frac{1}{iqr} \left( e^{iqr} - e^{-iqr} \right) \mathrm{d}r
\\
= \frac{2\pi}{iq} \int_{r=0}^\infty \left( e^{-(m-iq)r} - e^{-(m+iq)r} \right) \mathrm{d}r
\\
= \frac{2\pi}{iq} \int \left[ \frac{1}{-(m-iq)}e^{-(m-iq)r} - \frac{1}{-(m+iq)}e^{-(m+iq)r} \right]_{r=0}^\infty \mathrm{d}r
\\
= \frac{2\pi}{iq} \left( -\frac{1}{-(m-iq)} + \frac{1}{-(m+iq)} \right)
\\
= \frac{2\pi}{iq} \frac{2iq}{m^2+q^2}
= \frac{4\pi}{m^2+q^2}
.
$$

Comment: I really appreciate your nice explanation and your help. I got it properly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

We can also view the integral as the Fourier transform of $f(\mathbf{r}) := \frac{e^{-m|\mathbf r|}}{|\mathbf r|\}.$

As a distribution, $f$ satisfies the differential equation
$\Delta f - m^2 f = -4\pi\delta,$
where $Delta$ is the Laplace operator.

Taking the Fourier transform of this equation gives
$$-|\mathbf{q}|^2 \hat f(\mathbf{q}) - m^2 \hat f(\mathbf{q}) = -4\pi$$
i.e.
$$
\hat{f}(\mathbf{q}) = \frac{4\pi}{m^2+|\mathbf{q}|^2}.
$$

The "hard" part here is to show that $f$ satisfies that differential equation. For $r>0$ a direct calculation gives $\Delta f = m^2 f.$ At origin we essentially have a $\frac{1}{r}$ behavior, contributing with $\Delta(\frac{1}{r}) = -4\pi\delta.$

Comment: But $\hat f(q)=4\pi/m^2+q^2$ is not the most general solution to your second equation, no? So you need some boundary condition or similar to single out this solution, no?!

Comment: @Jakob. Yes, it is the most general solution, since $m^2+q^2$ has no zeros (unless $m=0$).

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was missing this. Thank you for the respond. Because if we have $=0$, then $+\mathrm{const.}\delta()$ could be added to $$, correct? But, as you point out, since $m^2+q^2\neq 0$, here this would amount to trivially add a zero.

Comment: @Jakob. If $m=0$ then we have $q^2$ as a factor and we could add both a $A \delta(\mathbf q)$ term and a $\mathbf B\cdot\nabla\delta(\mathbf q)$ term, where $A$ and $\mathbf B$ are constants.